# Java Quiz (Shuffling Answers)

Tags: java, shuffle

I am currently working on a schoolwork assignment to create a quiz demo in java. However, when I shuffle the question answer options, the correct answer index is mixed up and I cannot fix it. Please help. Thank you

Shuffle method:
private String[] shuffleOptions(String[] options, int answer) {
Random ran = new Random();

```
    // Answer value before shuffling
    String answerValue = options[answer];
    
    // Shuffle options randomly
    for (int i = options.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = ran.nextInt(i + 1);
        String temp = options[index];
        options[index] = options[i];
        options[i] = temp;
    }

    // Find the new correct answer index after shuffling
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].equals(answerValue)) {
            answerTemp = i;
        }
    }
    
    return options;
 }
```

Use:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quiz {
 private String name;
 private Question[] questions;
 private int capacity;
 private int size;
 private int score;
 
 private int answerTemp;

Quiz(){
    this.name = "Quiz" + String.valueOf(Math.random()*1000);
    this.questions = new Question[5];
    this.capacity = 5;
    this.size = 0;
    this.score = 0;
    
    this.answerTemp = 0;
}

private void increaseCapacity() { // Creates new quiz with double capacity/length for questions
    capacity *= 2;
    Question[] doubleQuestions = new Question[capacity];
    if (size > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(questions, 0, doubleQuestions, 0, size);
    }
    
    questions = doubleQuestions;
}

public void addQuestion(Question question) {
    if (size >= capacity) { // Reaches max capacity/length of questions
        increaseCapacity();
    } 
    
    questions[size++] = question;
}

private String[] shuffleOptions(String[] options, int answer) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    
     // Answer value before shuffling
    String answerValue = options[answer];
    
    // Shuffle options randomly
    for (int i = options.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = ran.nextInt(i + 1);
        String temp = options[index];
        options[index] = options[i];
        options[i] = temp;
    }

    // Find the new correct answer index after shuffling
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].equals(answerValue)) {
            answerTemp = i;
        }
    }
    
    return options;
 }

private String finalScore() { //Returns (percentage) final score
    int finalScore = (int) ((double) score / size * 100);
    return("FINAL SCORE: " + finalScore + "%" + "!");
}

public void giveQuiz() {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userAnswer = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         Question currentQuestion = questions[i];
         System.out.println("Question " + (i + 1) + ") : " + currentQuestion.getQuestion());
         String[] shuffledOptions = shuffleOptions(currentQuestion.getOptions(), currentQuestion.getAnswer());
         currentQuestion.setAnswer(answerTemp); // Sets correct answer value to index
         
         for (int x = 0; x < shuffledOptions.length; x++) { // Prints shuffled options
             System.out.println("(" + (x + 1) + ") " + shuffledOptions[x]);
         }
         
         System.out.println("\n Type Answer (1-4): ");
         userAnswer = userInput.nextInt();
         
         if (userAnswer == currentQuestion.getAnswer()) { //Checks for correct answer
             System.out.println("\nCORRECT ANSWER");
             score++;
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("\nWRONG ANSWER");
         }
    }
    
    System.out.println(finalScore());
    userInput.close();
  } //end of giveQuiz
}
```

Input number for correct answer
Outputs incorrect

Comment: So, instead of using the index for the answer, actually keep the answer as a `String` which can be matched back to the original questions.  That, or wrap the concept into a seperate class, one which has the question text and a boolean indicating if it's the actual answer

Comment: I would do that, but for the assignment we have to use the index. "it should have an integer in the range of 1-4, representing the correct answer"

Comment: Instead of passing in the options and index as separate parameters, You could pass in the entire Question. Then you can sort the options and update the index directly in the question object. Then you don't have a method that relies on your to update an instance variable in your class from the method.

Comment: Don't edit your question by using the "back" button of the browser. This loses updates done by others to make your question more readable. Instead, click on the "Edit" link.

Comment: Hi @LMJava! Have you considered shuffling the indices in a first step? You might get a result such as `{ 3, 0, 1, 2 }`. You could now move all the answers while still knowing which the correct answer was (Index 0 is now 3, etc.).
You would not even have to shuffle the answers, but that's another topic...

Answer (score 0):

Your user input starts with 1, but your answer starts with 0
This is your user input

```java
System.out.println("\n Type Answer (1-4): ");
userAnswer = userInput.nextInt();
```

This is the answer generate process

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].equals(answerValue)) {
            answerTemp = i;
        }
    }
```

If the first answer is correct, then the `answerTemp` is 0 instead of 1, that's the problem